# Положить изображение на бэкграунд, C# .NETCore

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, instagram-api

Есть необходимость запостить фото в инстаграм, используя нугет пакет InstagramApiSharp

При постинге изображения с размером 1280x1850(соотношение сторон 0.69) инстаграм возвращает ошибку "Incorrect aspect ratio"

Если скачать изображение из альбома инстаграма, то видно что там у них соотношение сторон 0.8

И картинка с таким соотношением успешно постится через api

Можно через какой-нибудь imageSharp отресайзить картинку до нужного соотношения,

```
using (Image image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream))
      {
       float needWidth = 800;
       float needHeight = 1000;

       image.Mutate(x => x
            .Resize((int)needWidth, (int)needHeight));
       }
image.SaveAsJpeg(stream, new JpegEncoder() { Subsample = JpegSubsample.Ratio420 });
```

но она, разумеется, растянется и будет выглядеть плохо.
Поэтому я подумал - а может сделать бэкграунд нужного размера, и в него вписать нашу картинку с нужным соотношением сторон? Но даже нет идей, как это сделать, поиск по бэкграунду в шарпе выдает смену бэкграунда в десктопных приложениях, а не по редактированию изображений.

Собственно, вот вопросы:

1)Имеет ли смысл делать это через бэкграунд, или есть другой, лучший путь? Конечная цель - постить в инстаграмм картинку любого соотношения сторон.

2)Если все таки бэкграунд, то как это реализовать?

Comment: Если использовать бэкграунд, то при наложении картинки останутся незаполненные поля, например, справа и внизу. На мой взгляд, лучше обрезать изображение под нужное соотношение сторон.

Comment: @Bulson это тоже хороший вариант! Можете расписать, как это сделать, если я хочу обрезать фото сверху, снизу или посередине?